# IntelliJ Import project without Welcome Screen

Tags: intellij-idea

The IntelliJ welcome screen has an *Import Project* button. Is there a way to import a project without going to the welcome screen?
[image]

Comment: Did you try File | Open (where you can point to pom.xml or build.gradle) or File | New | Project From Existing Sources?

Comment: @CrazyCoder 's comment should answer your question. Just to add on here, Open will keep the current configuration (.idea folder), while Import from Existing Sources lets you override the configuration.

Comment: Thanks, this works @CrazyCoder.

Comment: On a related note: [*After importing a Maven project into IntelliJ 2019.3, the bundled classes are not on class path*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58987498/642706)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `File` | **Open** (where you can point to `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`) or `File` | `New` | **Project From Existing Sources**.

If you have an existing IntelliJ IDEA project, use `File` | **Open** and point to the location of the project directory (the one containing `.idea` subdirectory).