# After importing a Maven project into IntelliJ 2019.3, the bundled classes are not on class path

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, vaadin, classpath, vaadin-flow

After importing a newly created Vaadin 14.0.x project, and using the `Import Project` feature to create a Maven-driven project in IntelliJ 2019.3 EAP, I get a message saying "Cannot resolving symbol". The error message offers me a button to "Add library … to classpath". But the necessary libraries are already loaded by Maven as dependencies. So this makes no sense.

[image: screenshot of error message in IntelliJ]

I retried the import 3 times. On each effort I opened another project to run the `File` > `Invalidate Caches / Restart` menu item. This action avoids known IntelliJ bugs/anti-features with creating a new project with same name as a deleted project.

[image: Screenshot of Welcome to IntelliJ IDEA dialog box, with callouts noting the failure of <code>Import Project</code> and the success of <code>Open</code>.]

Eventually I tried using the `Open` feature of the "Welcome to IntelliJ IDEA` panel. Amazingly, no such problem. All the classes are recognized by the IntelliJ code editor.

Bizarre, as I am opening each time a fresh unzipped copy of the original project created by the [*Getting Started with Vaadin*](https://vaadin.com/start/latest) page. There is some major difference between using `Open` versus `Import Project` in IntelliJ.

Comment: I would say check the build on command line first cause I expect that some of the dependencies of Vaadin 14 are not available via Central repository which means you have to add repositories to your settings.xml or in case of a repository to your repository manager ...

Comment: Since it's an EAP and your question implies, that it worked just fine with previous versions, you could file a ticket.

Comment: @cfrick Thanks to you I went back to report a bug. While experimenting to recreate the problem, I realized I had used the default option when importing a project rather than importing specifically as a Maven-driven project. See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59013219/642706). So this behavior seems to be a feature, not a bug.

Comment: On a related note: [*IntelliJ Import project without Welcome Screen*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50938188/642706)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Avoid `Create project from existing sources` option

I suspect that when you chose the `Import Project` route, you accepted the default option in the resulting dialog box. Do *not* use that option.

### ❌

[image: Screenshot of <code>Import Project</code> > <code>Create project from existing sources</code>]

That option, `Create project from existing sources` will fail in your situation. The [documentation for that dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2019.3/import-project-or-module-wizard.html?utm_campaign=IU&utm_medium=link&utm_source=product&utm_content=2019.3) unfortunately does not explain the first item. But option seems to expect a fully-formed project folder. Yours is not, apparently.

## Use `Import project from external model` option

Instead, choose the second option, `Import project from external model`. Select `Maven` from the list, in your case, for a Vaadin 14 project.

### ✅

[image: Screenshot of <code>Import Project</code> > <code>Import project from external model</code>.]

Note that with this option, you go through a series of dialogs [Wizard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizard_(software))-style. Whereas, with the first option, you directly opened the project.

Using this second option, and completing the series of dialogs, will yield an operational Vaadin 14 project.

Answer (score 1):

The best advice is "dont use the Import Project" feature. It's always been a little buggy / cumbersome ;)

Simply check out your project, and open the project's root folder (containing the parent `pom.xml`) in IntelliJ.

Incidentally, after checking out from git, the "Would you like to open this project in IntelliJ?" has also been buggy in the past. As a habit I answer "no" to this question and use File -> Open to open the new project manually.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it is simply buggy. I would have expected the opposite, that simply opening would be buggy and the formal importer would be successful.